Windows 10 news and interests and weather widget stuck
After I reboot my Windows 10 PC that little panel showing weather works and when I click on it it shows news, stock info and other things. It doesn't take long though and it just stops reacting and showing news and the temperature info also seems stuck! Switching it off and on does NOT fix it! Can I fix that somehow?
EDIT: also start menu search seems to be broken often - after typing something it searches for few seconds and then the box disappears
